# Error pulling data to dropdown menu from a MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

it's me again.
I am trying to make a dropdown menu that will request it's data from a MySQL database (`rows: category_id(a_i), category`) and display it in the dropdown menu. When new rows are added, the dropdown menu should expand to house them. This is the code I've created so far:

```
<select>
    <select name="submit" id="category">
        <option>Select category</option>
<?php
    $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
    $query->execute();
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['']; ?>"></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

db variable:

```
<?php
$db =mysqli_connect('localhost','xxx','xxx','xxx') or die('error with connection');
?>
```

However this code displays this error that I'm unable to fix on my own:
Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_query()

Comment: the error is just for this dropdown or for any query - like display count(*) from categories?

Comment: you are using both mysqli and mysql statements, you have to use either one or the other.  i would go with the mysqli statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what column name you are interested in putting in your dropdown so I have used `FIELDNAME`.

Try this see if it gives you enough of a start to finish it yourself.

```
<select name="submit" id="category">
    <option value="0">Select category</option>
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM categories");
    if ( $result ) {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {

            echo '<option value="' . $row['FIELDNAME'] . '">' . $row['FIELDNAME'] . '</option>';

        }
    } else {
        // query failed so output some error info
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks man! I am starting to like this website more and more!